# Change Text of a span if div has a certain class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div class="circle done">
<span class="label">1</span>
```

my code is above
I want to change 1 into a tick if div has "done" class 
How do I do that ?

Comment: I dont want to do it on click, i want to do it when page is loaded

Comment: Do you have jQuery linked in your page?

Comment: Post what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Using jquery: `$(".done span").text("new text")`

Comment: $(".done span").text("new text") this works 
thanks

Comment: Don't forget to add this to your body: **<body onLoad="YourFunction()">**. This way it'll execute on page load

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".done span.label").html("your tick html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your body tag:

```
<body onLoad="tick()">
```

And add this in your javascript

```
function tick(){
var labeltext = $('.label').val();
if (labeltext == "1"){
  $('.done').text("✓");
}else{}
};
```

Comment: why bind to an onload like that - if you are using jquery, then either just put your code at the bottom of the page or put it in a dom ready wrapper, there is no need to bind it using an element's attribute

Comment: @Pete True. It's a way you like to work I guess. Usually I put all my scripts in the same way/place and try to keep my html as clean as possible. But I see where you coming from and I **do** agree.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );
   const el = $(".circle");
   if (el.hasClass('done')) {
      $( "span.label" ).html('done');
   }
 });
```

This is done with jQuery, you first wait for the DOM to load, once it has. Then check if 'done' class is applied to the element if it is then change content of the `span` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
        $(".done").next("span").html("&#10004;");
    }
  );
```